# How to calculate the number of transits through a defined spatial polygon in R? (GPS data)

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

I am a beginner user of R and I want to calculate the number of transits through a defined spatial polygon. The structure of my data (a moving car) is the following:

```
`'data.frame':  4473 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ TIMESTAMP   : POSIXct, format: "2018-08-30 14:52:00" "2018-08-30 14:51:55" "2018-08-30 14:51:53" "2018-08-30 14:51:52" ...
 $ GPSLongitude: num  22.9 22.9 22.9 22.9 22.9 ...
 $ GPSLatitude : num  40.6 40.6 40.6 40.6 40.6 ...
 $ GPSHeading  : chr  "40,09" "41,67" "328,92" "328,92" ...
 $ GPSSpeed    : num  36 18 0 0 0 3.6 10.8 14.4 14.4 14.4 ...
```

Moreover, I have defined the following spatial polygon:

```
x_coord<- c(22.94202200198221, 22.94212252387121, 22.94187209650147, 22.94177280002484) #coord from google earth
y_coord<- c(40.63327268950896, 40.63337668693983, 40.63351336486517, 40.6334113055307)  #coord from google earth
xycoord<- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)
pol = Polygon(xycoord)
ps = Polygons(list(pol),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
```

I have tried the function `pnt.in.poly(sample_data[,2:3], xycoord)` in order to find the points which lie within the limits of the polygon but I want to find the number of the transits.
Here is a map with the plotted points:

[image: plotted points image] (red colour: polygon, green-yellow colours: 2 transits)

Finally, I want to know how many times the driver passed through the polygon and the points that belong to each transit (e.g. the first transit (green) consists of the points 345-355 and the second transit (yellow) consists of the points 1203-1220). Of course the driver passed through the polygon at different times of the day.

Thank you in advance!